# How can i use a function from a Activity Class in a non-Activity Class

Tags: java, android

i have two class in my project.the first one is" public class Schtimetable extends Activity" in which there is a method i need to call in Class B :"public class ClassMode" .The method is

```
public int calculateWeeks() {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("currentWeek",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int csweek = preferences.getInt("CSweek", 1);
    int weekofyear = preferences.getInt("currentWeek", 0);
    int now_weekofyear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
    return (csweek + now_weekofyear - weekofyear);// return current week
}
```

i find i can't use it just like this:

```
Schtimetable s = new Schtimetable();
    int oddOReven = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("oddOReven"));
    cursor.close();
    if ((s.calculateWeeks() % 2 == oddOReven) || (oddOReven == 2)) {
        Log.i(TAG, "has Class is true");
        return true;
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "has Class is false");
        return false;
    }
```

in all,i want to have a data by the method calculateweeks() returned,how can i get it.
Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Don't call methods from activities. Activities are meant to be started, not instantiated like a plain old java object. Place the method elsewhere (in some other helper class) and have it take a Context as an argument (so you can get the SharedPreferences). Then, in any activity you can call that method. Also, you should probably make the method static.

Comment: but i can't make the method static,because the getSharedPreferences is not a static method.

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
 YourActivtyClass activityclassobject = new YourActivtyClass();

 activityclassobject.activityclassmethod();
```

use this in your non activity class

which is called from another activity class...

i hope you understand process to call method..